# Linux (redhat) how to change password to previous password

Tags: passwords, redhat-enterprise-linux

Is there a way to change password to value same as the previous password?
I know this is a security flaw, but would like to know however.

when I try this:

```
[mrbean@wwwserver ~]$ passwd
Changing password for user mrbean.
Changing password for mrbean
(current) UNIX password: 
New UNIX password: -- here i typed same password
BAD PASSWORD: is too similar to the old one.
```

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/44276/ignore-bad-new-and-old-password-are-too-similar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either enter the password as root, or modify the PAM configuration to relax the password requirements. Either way, this is something that only root can do.

Comment: This is the technical answer.  The security aware answer is, "Don't do it outside a sandbox."  I know he says he realizes it's a security flaw.  I don't think he realizes the seriousness of the vulnerability.

Answer (score 2):

or change it to something else, then change it back to same one...

Comment: Unless something like pam_pwhistory is in use.

Comment: If an organization is using a requirement to make the password different, it's probably implementing history too, to avoid this.  And possibly a min password age to make this harder to do.